# passing objects as arguments

Tags: c++

Can anyone give example about passing an object of a class as argument to the function of same class.

Comment: What, exactly, are you confused about?  If you could clarify your question, we could probably give more useful answers.

Comment: The copy constructor is probably the most classic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class X
{
public:
    void func(X x) {}
};

int main()
{
    X a,b;
    a.func(b);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
class Unicorn {
    void Eat(Unicorn other_unicorn) { 
        // implementation omitted to keep this answer family-friendly
    }
};

int main() {
    Unicorn glitter;
    Unicorn dazzle;
    glitter.Eat(dazzle); // mmmm, yummy
}
```

Note that Dazzle is still alright because we made a copy of him and fed the copy to Glitter.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be pedantic, I'd recommend passing objects by reference, and making them const by default, eg (with thanks to James McNellis)

```
class Unicorn {
    void Eat(const Unicorn & other) {
        // Nothing else changes
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this what you want but anyways

```
    class MyClass {  int a; void whatEver(MyClass myclass); };

void MyClass::whatEver(MyClass myclass) { ....do something }
```

and now somewhere in the code

```
MyClass obj1; obj2;

obj1.whatEver(obj2);
```